# Changing file name and adding some line in it

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a series of files as below :

```
000_0123
000_0234
000_0345
000_0456 
000_0678 
000_0890
000_01123
000_01234
```

I want to change the names to :

```
000_123
000_234
000_345
000_456 
000_678 
000_890
000_1123
000_1234
```

and I want to add first line in each file as  "`#include<conio.h>`". Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add your line to the start of each file you could do

```
for i in 000*; do sed '1i#include<conio.h>' "$i"; done
```

`1i` means insert this at the first line (before existing first line). The existing first line becomes line 2. A warning: this command will fail (do nothing) for empty files.

The contents of all the files with the added line will appear in the terminal one after the other. If it looks right, then do again with `-i` to change the files in place

```
for i in 000*; do sed -i '1i#include<conio.h>' "$i"; done
```

If you just want to remove the leading `0` from after `_` you could use `rename` to rename the files...

```
rename 's/0_0/0_/' 000*
```

Comment: Once again you help me , thank you , work for me , accepted ...

Comment: my pleasure as always :D